# My Vec3 class initialises without coding for it. How?

Tags: c++

I made a custom vector3 class. In the class, I did not made a code that initializes via curly braces. However the code runs, even without coding it.

This works:

```
Vec3 pos = {1,1,0};
```

but I never coded for curly braces. How ?????? How it works ????????

This is my vec3 class header

```
class Vec3
{
private:
    float* data;
public:
    //float* data;
    // constructors
    Vec3();
    Vec3(float x, float y, float z);
    Vec3(Vec3&);
    Vec3(Vec3&&);
    ~Vec3();
    // getters setters
    float getX();   float getY();   float getZ();
    void setX(float);   void setY(float); void setZ(float);

    float& operator[](int);

    // maths
    float magnitude();
    Vec3& operator=(Vec3&);
    Vec3& operator=(Vec3&&);
    Vec3 operator-();
    friend Vec3 operator+(Vec3&, Vec3&);  friend Vec3 operator+(Vec3&, Vec3&&);  friend Vec3 operator+(Vec3&&, Vec3&);  friend Vec3 operator+(Vec3&&, Vec3&&);
    friend Vec3 operator-(Vec3&, Vec3&);  friend Vec3 operator-(Vec3&, Vec3&&);  friend Vec3 operator-(Vec3&&, Vec3&);  friend Vec3 operator-(Vec3&&, Vec3&&);
    friend float operator*(Vec3&, Vec3&); friend float operator*(Vec3&, Vec3&&); friend float operator*(Vec3&&, Vec3&); friend float operator*(Vec3&&, Vec3&&);
    friend Vec3 operator%(Vec3&, Vec3&);  friend Vec3 operator%(Vec3&, Vec3&&); friend Vec3 operator%(Vec3&&, Vec3&);  friend Vec3 operator%(Vec3&&, Vec3&&); 
    friend Vec3 operator*(float, Vec3&);
    friend Vec3 operator*(float, Vec3&&);


    // logical
    friend bool operator==(Vec3&, Vec3&); friend bool operator==(Vec3&, Vec3&&); friend bool operator==(Vec3&&, Vec3&); friend bool operator==(Vec3&&, Vec3&&);
    // output
    friend std::ostream & operator << (std::ostream& out, const Vec3& v);

};
```

Comment: You have a constructor with 3 args: `Vec3(float x, float y, float z)`.

Comment: [OT] `float* data;` is suspicious for `Vec3`, should it be `float data[3];` to avoid memory management?

Comment: [OT]: some methods (as getters) should be `const`. And all `Vec3&` should be `const Vec3&`.

Comment: I'm assuming you're using "new" to allocate the data on the heap: this is a bad design.  It's better to simply make the data a member of the class.

Answer (score 0):

Vec3(float x, float y, float z); does this for as you have defined it already in your class.

Comment: Thanks. Sorry I am so noob for this. Can you elaborate plz. How this maps to curly braced array. How this works behind the scene.

Answer (score 0):

The statement `Vec3 pos = {1,1,0};` is a [*copy-list-initialisation*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization). `{1,1,0}` is not (always) an array expression, absent of context it does not have a type.

This looks at the constructors of `Vec3` and finds `Vec3(float x, float y, float z);` as the best match for those arguments.

Comment: That explains it. Thank you very much.